# Launch multiple and parallel forms and update them in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, forms

I am writing a software where I need to create N forms and update them in real time from an application console.

I post here an example:

```
//THE DIMENSION OF o IS VARIABLE, IT CAN RANGE FROM 0 TO 5
//o LENGTH DEFINE HOW MANY PARALLEL FROMS MUST BE LAUNCHED AND o CONTENT DEFINE THE FORM TITLE
//osc IS A List<Osci>

public void read()
{ 
    //Create N thread
    Thread[] oscThread = new Thread[o.Length];

    for(int i = 0;i<o.Length; i++)
    {
        oscThread[i] = new Thread(new ThreadStart(OsciThreadProc));
        oscThread[i].Start();
        osc[i].setTitle("form n. " + o[i]);
    }

    //loop until the thread must be alive
    while (!suspendThread)
    {
        //HERE I GET A NEW LINE OF MY RAW DATA
        rawData myTemporaryRaw = getRawData();
        //HERE I RETURN THE DATA ANALYZED 
        int[] data = AnalyzeRaw(myTemporaryRaw);

        //UPDATE FORM CONTENT
        //O CONTENT MATCH WITH Data VALUE
         for(int j = 0; j < o.Length; j++)
         {
            osc[j].Draw(data[o[j]]);
         }  
    }
}

private void OsciThreadProc()
{
    var myOsc = new Osci();
    osc.Add(myOsc);
    myOsc.ShowDialog();
}
```

It is a console application (here, for simplicity I posted only a couple of methods) that must launch n forms and update them with a flow of content.

The form code is:

```
//THIS FORM HAS ONLY A LABEL valueLabel
public partial class Oscilloscope : Form
{
    public Osci()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Osci(int c)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Osci_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    internal void setTitle(string title)
    {
        Text = title;
    }

    internal void Draw(int v)
    {
        valueLabel.Text = v.ToString();
    }
}
```

When I start this program, it launch an Exception (`'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException'`) on `osc[i].setTitle("form n. " + o[i]);`. Probably it try to get the new value, that are performed in the second method, before then first method.

Anyway, I think also that my way is not the best way in order to launch parallel forms and update them with a flow of information.

Can you sudgest to me a better way?

Comment: Where do you declare `o`?  All forms have to be on the GUI thread.  ShowDialog blocks.

Comment: It's problematic to have global data like `osc` and let multiple threads access it. Better make a vector of objects each owning a thread and have them each have their own data. In your case, the thread has not finished the `osc.Add(myOsc);` part while your main thread is already trying to access the new `osci`.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that `osc` and `o` have equal dimensions at the moment of the error? It seems to me that they do not. So the error is only in that.